# R Shiny / Leaflet: select the point closest to the map center

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

This simple shiny app lets the user drag around a map, and shows the ZIP code whose centroid is closest to the map center.

The problem is that the reactive object holding the zip code closest to the map center loads a ZIP code when the app initializes, and never changes.

On the other hand,if I choose to show all ZIP code centroids within the map borders, it works as expected. Both expressions are very similar, but nevertheless one works while the other doesn't.

What's going on?

Reproducible code:

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)

# List of ZIP code centroids as X/Y coordinates
zip_coord <- read.csv('https://www.dropbox.com/s/lz9gmrz5skvef53/zip_coord.csv?dl=1')

# Default view location
lat <- 42.361145
lng <-  -71.057083
zoom <- 11



ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(fluidRow(
  column(
  7,
  offset = 1,
  leafletOutput("map", height = "700")),
  column(
  3,
  h5("This doesn't work: It always shows the same ZIP:"),
  tableOutput("centerZip"),
  br(),
  h5("This works: the ZIPs change as you move the map around:"),
  tableOutput("inBoundsZIPs")
  )
  )))


server <- (function(input, output, session) {

  output$map <- renderLeaflet({

    leaflet() %>%
      addProviderTiles("Stamen.TonerLite", group = "Stamen.TonerLite") %>%
      setView(lat = lat,
              lng = lng,
              zoom = zoom)
  })


  # A reactive expression that returns a single zip code, the one closest to the center 
  # of the current map view
  # THIS DOES NOT WORK AS EXPECTED

  centeredZip <- reactive({
    if (is.null(input$map_bounds))
      return(NULL)
    bounds <- input$map_bounds
    center <- c(mean(bounds$north, bounds$south),
                mean(bounds$east, bounds$west))

    nearest.zip <- zip_coord[which.min(colSums((t(zip_coord[-1]) - center)^2)),1]
    # Pick out the point
    subset(zip_coord, ZIP == nearest.zip)

  })

    output$centerZip <- renderTable({
      centeredZip()
    })

  # A reactive expression that returns the set of zips that are
  # within the current view bounds
  # THIS WORKS AS EXPECTED

  zipsInBounds <- reactive({
    if (is.null(input$map_bounds))
      return(zip_coord[FALSE,])
    bounds <- input$map_bounds
    latRng <- range(bounds$north, bounds$south)
    lngRng <- range(bounds$east, bounds$west)

    subset(zip_coord,
           lat >= latRng[1] & lat <= latRng[2] &
             long >= lngRng[1] & long <= lngRng[2], select = ZIP)
  })


  output$inBoundsZIPs <- renderTable({
    zipsInBounds()
  })


})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

EDIT:

Turns out I had my longitude and latitude definition for the center point backwards. Instead of

```
center <- c(mean(bounds$north, bounds$south), mean(bounds$east, bounds$west))
```

it should be:

`center <- c(mean(bounds$east, bounds$west), mean(bounds$north, bounds$south))`

The zipcode selector function was correct after all: given that my center definition was mistakenly placed in another hemisphere, the closest zipcode to it was always the same.

The final, and working version is:

```
# List of ZIP code centroids as X/Y coordinates
zip_coord <- read.csv('https://www.dropbox.com/s/lz9gmrz5skvef53/zip_coord.csv?dl=1')

# Default view location
lat <- 42.361145
lng <-  -71.057083
zoom <- 11



ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(fluidRow(
  column(
    7,
    offset = 1,
    leafletOutput("map", height = "700")),
  column(
    3,
    h5("This doesn't work: It always shows the same ZIP:"),
    tableOutput("centerZip"),
    br(),
    h5("This works: the ZIPs change as you move the map around:"),
    tableOutput("inBoundsZIPs")
  )
)))


server <- (function(input, output, session) {

  output$map <- renderLeaflet({

    leaflet() %>%
      addProviderTiles("Stamen.TonerLite", group = "Stamen.TonerLite") %>%
      setView(lat = lat,
              lng = lng,
              zoom = zoom)
  })


  # A reactive expression that returns a single zip code, the one closest to the center 
  # of the current map view
  # NOW THIS WORKS TOO!

  centeredZip <- reactive({
    if (is.null(input$map_bounds))
      return(NULL)
    bounds <- input$map_bounds
    center <- c(mean(bounds$east, bounds$west),
                mean(bounds$north, bounds$south)
                )

    nearest.zip <- zip_coord[which.min(colSums((t(zip_coord[-1]) - center)^2)),1]
    # Pick out the point
    subset(zip_coord, ZIP == nearest.zip)

  })

  output$centerZip <- renderTable({
    centeredZip()
  })

  # A reactive expression that returns the set of zips that are
  # within the current view bounds
  # THIS WORKS AS EXPECTED

  zipsInBounds <- reactive({
    if (is.null(input$map_bounds))
      return(zip_coord[FALSE,])
    bounds <- input$map_bounds
    latRng <- range(bounds$north, bounds$south)
    lngRng <- range(bounds$east, bounds$west)

    subset(zip_coord,
           lat >= latRng[1] & lat <= latRng[2] &
             long >= lngRng[1] & long <= lngRng[2], select = ZIP)
  })


  output$inBoundsZIPs <- renderTable({
    zipsInBounds()
  })


})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had my longitude and latitude definition for the center point backwards. 
Instead of 
`center <- c(mean(bounds$north, bounds$south), mean(bounds$east, bounds$west))` 
it should be:
`center <- c(mean(bounds$east, bounds$west), mean(bounds$north, bounds$south))`.
The zipcode selector function was correct after all: given that my center definition was mistakenly placed in another hemisphere, the closest zipcode to it was always the same.

Comment: My goal was to get the top table rendering each time, good that you found the solution you were looking for

Comment: I get that, and appreciate the swift answer. Regarding the solution I was looking for, it was explicit in the title ("select the point closest to the map center")

Answer (score 1):

I've found the issue,try this

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)

# List of ZIP code centroids as X/Y coordinates
zip_coord <- read.csv('http://www.dropbox.com/s/lz9gmrz5skvef53/zip_coord.csv?dl=1')

# Default view location
lat <- 42.361145
lng <-  -71.057083
zoom <- 11

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(fluidRow(
  column(
    7,
    offset = 1,
    leafletOutput("map", height = "700")),
  column(
    3,
    h5("This doesn't work: It always shows the same ZIP:"),
    tableOutput("centerZip"),
    br(),
    h5("This works: the ZIPs change as you move the map around:"),
    tableOutput("inBoundsZIPs")
  )
)))


server <- (function(input, output, session) {

  output$map <- renderLeaflet({

    leaflet() %>%
      addProviderTiles("Stamen.TonerLite", group = "Stamen.TonerLite") %>%
      setView(lat = lat,
              lng = lng,
              zoom = zoom)
  })


  # A reactive expression that returns a single zip code, the one closest to the center 
  # of the current map view
  # THIS DOES NOT WORK AS EXPECTED

  centeredZip <- eventReactive(input$map_bounds,{
    if (is.null(input$map_bounds))
      return(NULL)
    bounds <- input$map_bounds
    center <- c(mean(bounds$north, bounds$south),mean(bounds$east, bounds$west))
    #center <- c( 42.65214,-71.43929)
    nearest.zip <- zip_coord[which.min(colSums(t(zip_coord[-1]) - center)^2),1]    
    # Pick out the point
    subset(zip_coord, ZIP == nearest.zip)
  })

  output$centerZip <- renderTable({
    centeredZip()
  })

  # A reactive expression that returns the set of zips that are
  # within the current view bounds
  # THIS WORKS AS EXPECTED

  zipsInBounds <- reactive({
    if (is.null(input$map_bounds))
      return(zip_coord[FALSE,])
    bounds <- input$map_bounds
    latRng <- range(bounds$north, bounds$south)
    lngRng <- range(bounds$east, bounds$west)

    subset(zip_coord,
           lat >= latRng[1] & lat <= latRng[2] &
             long >= lngRng[1] & long <= lngRng[2], select = ZIP)
  })


  output$inBoundsZIPs <- renderTable({
    zipsInBounds()
  })


})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: That was it.

Instead of 
`zip_coord[which.min(colSums((t(zip_coord[-1]) - center)^2)),1]`

I needed
`zip_coord[which.min(colSums(t(zip_coord[-1]) - center)^2),1]`

The extra set of ()'s was screwing my code

Comment: It took me a while to figure out what was happening

Comment: After more careful testing, I realised that your solution doesn't actually show the closest zipcode to the map center - the problem was not in the zipcode row selection, it was in the center point definition